# concatenating NSStrings not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to concatenate the contents of an `NSMutableArray` using

```
NSString* result = @""; 

for(NSString* test in  self.selectedOnes) {

    NSLog(test) ; 
    [result stringByAppendingString:test];
    [result stringByAppendingString:@","];
}
```

but  `result` remains `@""`, I am sure that the `selectedOnes` contains data because it writes to the log.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringByAppendingString:` returns a new String.

This should work.

```
NSString* result = @""; 

for(NSString* test in  self.SelectedOnes  )
{
    NSLog( test ) ; 
    result = [result stringByAppendingString:test];
    result = [result stringByAppendingString:@","];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`componentsJoinedByString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString%3a) method which *"Constructs and returns an NSString object that is the result of interposing a given separator between the elements of the array"*,

```
NSString *result = [self.SelectedOnes componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 2):

`stringByAppendingString:` returns a new string

Use it like this:

```
NSString* result = @""; 

for(NSString* test in  self.SelectedOnes  )
{
    NSLog( test ) ; 



    result = [result stringByAppendingString:test];
    result = [result stringByAppendingString:@","];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
result = test;
result = [result stringByAppendingString:@","];
```